# PyMuPDF: skipping bad link / annot item 0

Tags: python, pymupdf

I use `PyMuPDF's` `insert_link` to add links to a PDF. But when I do it, I sometimes get the warning `skipping bad link / annot item 0`. When I highlight the same rect with `add_highlight_annot` the area is highlighted. There is just no link. This happens to some words, but I can't find a connection between them. What does the warning mean exactly?

Bellow is the code I use:

```
doc = fitz.open('test.pdf')
term = "hello"
for page in doc:
    rects = page.search_for(term)
    for rect in rects:
       page.add_highlight_annot(rect)
       l = {'kind': 2, 'from': rect, 'uri': link, 'id': ''}
       page.insert_link(l)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Turns out that the link text was of for some links and a `)` was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if some text of the link is not UTF-8 encodedable.
Internally in PyMuPDF's C code, PDF objects for defining the link are created from their representation as text source. The error occurs if the Python C-function `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` fails.
In your context most probably the URI text should be the problem.